# python - space in folder name

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this next bit of code

```
Path = os.getenv('PATH')
Path = Path.split(';')
for i, p in enumerate(Path):
    if len(P) != 0 and p[-1] != "\\":
        Path[i] = p + "\\" #this adds '\' to the ending of each line
```

printing
`Path[0]` will show

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\`

However, When I try to run anything from this folder, I get the error

`'C:\Program' is not recognized`

How can I make it search in the entire path and not stop at the space?

Comment: which command do you use to "run anything from this folder"? Try putting the path in quotation marks.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] that shows precisely how you use the path and how it fails.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to run.  How do you run it?  If using os.system, you probably want to use " for the path.  For example:

```
os.system("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\aaa.exe\"")
```

Assuming you are running C:\Program Files (x86)\aaa.exe.  Be aware of the two \" in the code.

Answer (score 0):

For good practices you never use spaces, for that you can select relative routes only inside the project, however if you really need to use spaces you can use:

`file =__import__=("folder path")`

this will import file as `folder path` separated with spaces.